# How to solve conflict between Ionic on-hold and ionic option button

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

In my current Ionic App, I have used **[on-hold()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onHold/)** and **[ion-option-button](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionOptionButton/)** on one element.

Now, `ion-option-button` is not working correctly, when I'm running my app on android device (cli: ionic run android), So I think they are having conflict with each other, (sometimes `ion-option-button` work and sometimes didn't work), because when I remove on-hold() the `ion-option-button` work properly and smooth

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved my problem at all. It sometimes has wrong, But better than before, It's satisfying.

```
  app.directive("myOnHold", ['$ionicGesture', function ($ionicGesture) {
     return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
           var handleDrag = function (e) {
              e.preventDefault()
           };

           var dragGesture = $ionicGesture.on('hold', handleDrag, $element);

           $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
              // Unbind drag gesture handler
              $ionicGesture.off(dragGesture, 'drag', handleDrag);
           });
        }
     }
  }])
```